# I am getting an error running a springboot application on intellij. Can someone help me?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

Why do I get this error connecting to a remote Oracle Database. I do have access rights and I can access the database through DataGrip。 It causes the application to close again.

```
WARN  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@fe13916]:java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.Connection
```

This is followed by a series of errors.

Finally,I get exception. At the root of caused by, it was

```
    ... 118 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:297)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:1350)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.addColumns(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:577)
    ... 138 common frames omitted
```

Was it because, the connection was abandoned pre-maturely?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown because you have abandoned connection pre-maturely prior to ResultSet object.(not sure!!)
Anyhow it could be better for us to help, if you share the code.